# Add validation rules on input type

Tags: javascript, validation, jqxwidgets

I would ask if is it possible to add validation rules directly on input element and then validate form before submission instead of specify a list of validation rules directly in the form.

something like

```
$('#element1′).rules("add", { … list of rules });
$('#element2′).rules("add", { … list of rules });

and then $('#form').validate({});
```

I’m developing using a tag library and to me this functionality comes very useful.

Is possible to do it with  jqxValidator component of jqWidjet library?

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from jqxWidjet forum is: it's not possible. Not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

.keydown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textinput").keydown(function (e) {
        ///validation here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the question is related to how to do it with  jqxValidator component of jqWidjet

Answer (score 0):

If you aim for HTML5 and understand regular expression you can use HTML5 pattern attribute:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the question is related to how to do it with jqxValidator component of jqWidjet